# swiping event handling

Tags: swipe

I am coding swipe to remove functions. It works fine on the first event but..if I swipe twice...it doesn't seem to work properly.

I don't know why "Delete" button disappears if I swipe left twice.

Please see my code below:

```
<div id="showlist">
<div id="btn_del">Delete</div>  
</div>

<style>
#showlist {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:#DDD;
border-bottom:1px dashed #666;
}

#btn_del {
float:right;
margin-right:-60px;
background:red;
padding:5px;
display:none;margin; 
border:1px solid #FFF; 
margin-top:20px;
color:#FFF;
font:12px Arial;
font-wieght:bold;
border-radius:5px;
}
</style>

<script>
$('#showlist').bind({  
swipeleft: function() {    
$("#showlist").animate( {'width': '90%'}, 300 );
    $("#btn_del").fadeIn();

},  
swiperight: function() {    
$("#btn_del").hide();
$("#showlist").animate( {'width': '100%'}, 300 );
},
preventDefaultEvents: true
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Chae/uLwJg/2/

Any help would be very appreciated.

Chae from Seoul

Answer (score 0):

I have simply solved the problem myself.
I put the checking code for visibility of delete button object.

```
$('#showlist').bind({  

swipeleft: function() {   
  chk = $("#btn_del").is(':visible');
  if (!chk) {
     $("#showlist").animate( {'width': '90%'}, 300 );
     $("#btn_del").fadeIn();
  } 
},  

swiperight: function() {    
  $("#btn_del").hide();
  $("#showlist").animate( {'width': '100%'}, 300 );
},

preventDefaultEvents: true
});
```